# Fetch attributes from url decode (PHP)

Tags: php

Here is the code using which i am getting data:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$request = file_get_contents('php://input');
//$req_dump = print_r( $request, true );
$fp = file_put_contents( 'request.log', urldecode(json_encode($request)));

?>
```

output :

```
domain_prefix = test & payload = {
    "attributed_cost": "0.00",
    "count": 50,
    "id": "da674e25-5d9c-a8e2-1d5e-aa018b6cc1c3",
    "outlet": {
        "id": "3faf0608-91fa-11e3-a0f5-b8ca3a64f8f4",
        "name": "West End Shop",
        "tax_id": "e52b2846-e920-11e5-f98b-29c175501027",
        "time_zone": "Australia/Brisbane"
    },
    "outlet_id": "3faf0608-91fa-11e3-a0f5-b8ca3a64f8f4",
    "product": {
        "active": true,
        "attributed_cost": null,
        "base_name": "Test Productss",
        "button_order": null,
        "categories": [],
        "deleted_at": null,
        "description": "",
        "handle": "testproducts",
        "id": "bfe919c4-6357-46c9-a333-d1db636446c5",
        "name": "Test Productss",
        "sku": "10203",
        "source": "USER",
        "source_id": null,
        "source_variant_id": null,
        "supply_price": "0.00",
        "taxes": [{
            "outlet_id": "3faf0608-91fa-11e3-a0f5-b8ca3a64f8f4",
            "tax_id": "e52b2846-e920-11e5-f98b-29c175501027"
        }],
        "variant_options": [],
        "variant_parent_id": null
    },
    "product_id": "bfe919c4-6357-46c9-a333-d1db636446c5",
    "reorder_point": "0",
    "restock_level": "0",
    "version": 16073287694
} & retailer_id = 3 fa8309c - 91 fa - 11e3 - a0f5 - b8ca3a64f8f4 & type = inventory.update
```

I am not sure how to fetch "count" & "id" & "product_id" attributes value from this.
I have tried `parse_str` but it didn't work.
let me know your thoughts on this, how to fetch data from it ?
Thankyou

Comment: convert json to array then you will get attributes easy use `(json_decode($payload, true)` after finishing all the code I mean after $fp. if you did't get then frame proper json then send

Comment: notworking in code

Comment: then try with javascript, you can access json easy. or check with json format before sending to php file. if json not framed properly then json_decode is no use!

Comment: php should have some solution for this.

Comment: why you write "output:"? where it come from?

Comment: It comes from webhook.

Comment: no thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your $request is like that output then you can try
you can try

```
parse_str($request, $parse_request);
$payload = json_decode($parse_request["payload"], true);

$id =  $payload["id"];
$count =  $payload["count"];
$product_id =  $payload["product"]["id"];
```

Comment: $request = file_get_contents('php://input');
$parse_request = parse_str($request);
$payload = json_decode($parse_request["payload"], true);
$fp = file_put_contents( 'request.log', $payload["id"]);

Not working

Comment: could you post $request content, it easier for us to help if we knew the input

Comment: The data is coming from webhook. i just have the data which is output that i have posted in question.

Comment: my mistake incorrect way to use parse_str, just edit it. print $parse_request out for more detail